# How to consume JavaScript classes generated by WSDL utility?

Tags: javascript, web-services, proxy-classes, wsdl.exe

I generated classes in JavaScript from a WSDL by using Visual Studio's WSDL utility.

```
wsdl /o:SomeClasses.js /l:js https://SomeCompany.com/SomeService?WSDL
```

The output contains classes (in JavaScript) that look like this:

```
public System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1") System.SerializableAttribute() System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute() System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code") System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:some.company") 
class SomeUser {
    private var domainNameField : System.String;
    private var userNameField : System.String;

    ///<remarks/>
    public final function get domainName() : System.String {
        return this.domainNameField;
    }
    public final function set domainName(value : System.String) {
        this.domainNameField = value;
    }

    ///<remarks/>
    public final function get userName() : System.String {
        return this.userNameField;
    }
    public final function set userName(value : System.String) {
        this.userNameField = value;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write OOP JavaScript utilizing these classes? If so, what is the syntax, examples, etc.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support classes.

Comment: Y, I know... which is why I'm wondering why the WSDL utility generates this "javascript" code. Is there some way to use it??

Comment: That is NOT JavaScript. Looks like C#.

Comment: @Diodeus: That's JScript.NET, not C# and not JavaScript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify the **JS** language for the [Web Services Description Language Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx), **you are NOT specifying JavaScript, but JScript**. It's not even [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) that InternetExplorer can fully understand, it's [JScript.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript.NET).

JScript.NET is a server side scripting language based on JScript but with added features - available only on the server side - like the [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezts5hx6.aspx) you've got in the code you posted.

You should look for other ways of **generating JavaScript code**, maybe with a tool like [Wsdl2js](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2js/) or [performing your WS call with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call%20soap%20web%20service%20with%20jquery&tab=relevance). You can't use the Wsdl.exe generated code inside InternetExplorer as InternetExplorer only supports the old JScript language (and non IE browsers don't even support that).